# Vue: How to check multiple string in v-show

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm working form which will show specific `div` if the model value is equal to some specific string. This is how I'm checking but it's not working, what I'm doing wrong?

```
v-show="form.status === 'vh' || 'pr' || 'o'"
```

Comment: Most likely `v-show="form.status === 'vh' || form.status ===  'pr' || form.status ===  'o'"` no?

Comment: great that worked, thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That attribute value isn't a valid javascript expression.

You could modify it to:

```
v-show="form.status === 'vh' || form.status === 'pr' || form.status === 'o'"
```

for a quick win, or if you don't like attribute clutter, write a computed/getter for this expression in your script.

Comment: I think I will be fine with this, no need to write computed thank you :)

Answer (score 3):

You can use an array instead with `includes`/`indexOf > -1` (depending on your build setup / browser support) to avoid some repetition

```
v-show="['vh', 'pr', 'o'].includes(form.status)"
```